# Is it viable to have a SQL table with only one row and one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently working on my first application that uses a database so I'm very new to this. The database has multiple tables that are what you would expect to normally see.

However, I created one table which only has one row and one column used to keep a count of the total items processed by the program so it's available to access elsewhere. I can't just use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

because these items that I am processing I do not want to actually keep in a table.

It seems like a waste to use a table to store **one** value so I am wondering if there a better way to keep track of this value.

Comment: Yeah I tried to clarify that. I actually do have other uses for the database.

Comment: You should probably have a table that keeps track of the items being processed.  It sounds like you are dipping your little toe in the waters of databases and reluctant to jump.  It's summertime (in the northern hemisphere).  Jump.

Comment: it would be ok.  You might make it more generic by having a name value pair that you could use for multiple variables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the problem with that is that I am using a website's API to continuously retrieve all of the comments posted to that website, meaning that in one day the table could grow to well over a million rows if I made a row for every item. I have no use for that data and it'll eventually take up al the diskspace I have. I simply want a count to use for statistics.

Comment: @Ar7 . . . (1) It sounds like potentially useful data to me.  (2) A million rows is not very many rows.

Comment: Think to databases and tables as **persistence**: if you have to *persist* a result, it's the intended way to do it.

Comment: you could use a temp table, or what is the point of storing a count(*) if you could just call the count function by all the queries that need to use it?

Comment: (1) The useful data I extract and actually do maintain in a database. The rest I would like to discard. (2) I agree that is not much, but it is a million rows in **one** day for a program that I intend to run 24/7. The VPS I am running it on only has 40GB, and (given I made no mistakes in calculating) all 40GB would be consumed once the table grew to 500 million records. But to get back to the topic of the question, is it viable to have this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your table storing? it's storing some kind of processing audit. So make it a little more useful - add a column storing the last `datetime` that the data was processed. Add a column for the time it took to process. Add another column which stores the username (or some identifier) of whoever ran the process. Now add a row for every table that is processed (there's only one now but there might be more in future). Try and envisage how your processing is going to grow in future

Comment: That's actually an amazing idea that I didn't think of earlier

Comment: Cool. The trick is to think a little further forward, but avoid over engineering, which is just as bad as not thinking further forward. These kinds of tables are really useful for diagnosing issues that happened in the past. The next iteration of a table like this might be to store a record for every 'process' then you could see a preformance trend or identify unexpected 'processes' (rather than a row per table). Just depends what gives the most value for minimal complication